# Cannot start apache after editing the config httpd file for wsgi

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to deploy my homepage. I used pip install mod_wsgi to get the wsgi. And what I understood is that I only have to change the httpd file with the following:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/rasmus/MainSite/src/MainSite/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/rasmus/MainSite/src/MainSite

<Directory /home/rasmus/MainSite/src/MainSite>
  <Files wsgi.py>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Files>
</Directory>
```

I copied the directory below and pasted it into `Users/rasmus/` - And I read somewhere that the home directory was found by `%USERPROFILE%`which opens `Users` directory

[image]

When I try to start my apache server from services.msc I get the following error message:

[image]

It runs if I remove it. So the apache server should be working, and I guess it's my configuration for deployment in httpd config that that is wrong.

I use apache 2.4.25, Python 3.5.1 64-bit

EDIT:

typing mod_wsgi-express module-config yields:

[image]

Comment: /home/rasmus is not the same as /Users/rasmus.

Comment: @DanielRoseman can I then use my full path with C:/ to point to it?

Comment: I don't know much about Windows but I would imagine so.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Did not do the trick

Comment: Did you run ``mod_wsgi-express module-config`` to get the configuration you need to add to Apache to have it load mod_wsgi? See section 'Connecting into Apache installation' of https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi This is needed when using ``pip install`` method, but then using it with existing Apache system. You have to use this method on Windows when using ``pip install`` method as ``mod_wsgi-express start-server`` is not supported on Windows.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton No I did not. I think I also saw a blog post where you explain the installation. But I am not aware where I should execute this command? I tried run the command in my mod_wsgi directory. I edited my post with a picture of the results.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton This dosen't look right according to the example in the link. The example points to a .so file where as mine is a .pyd file. Can you see from the picture if it looks right?

Comment: Copy the exact output it produces and put it in your Apache configuration file before you try and use any mod_wsgi configuration directives. It does have to be outside of any ``VirtualHost`` though if you are using them. It is that simple. Different platforms do things differently, so it will not be the same as what you see on Linux.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Okey so that seems to be working, just copy  pasting it in. So I never have to edit these files?